# Delete git branches from text file

Tags: linux, shell

I have a remote git stash where all branches are present.
I did `git branch -a > branch.txt`
this creates a text file branch.txt with all the branches.
Now i want to delete specific branches but branch name is `remotes/origin/{branchname}`
how can i get only the branch name in shell script

Comment: do you have a list of branch names that needs to deleted

Comment: yes i have a specfic set of branches

Comment: `git branch -a | cut -f3 -d'/' > branch.txt` This helps?

Comment: So you just need to extract the final component of the full branch name? You could use the `basename` shell command to do that. Its intended application is to work on file pathnames, but it should work on anything that looks like a pathname.

Comment: thanks it works but i have certain branches that start with 'log/log1' type in that case it gives 'log1' while i want 'log/log1'

Comment: Then use `awk`, something like `awk -F 'origin/' '{print $2}'`

Comment: Ian Abbott can you please help with the command

Answer (score 0):

```
git branch -a | cut -f3 -d'/' > branch.txt
```

This might help you to extract the branch names only.